# Switching between two strings like booleans

Tags: string, lua, boolean

I often got objects which have a var that represents a state which is not boolans and want to switch them as simple as possible.

```
function switch_state()

  if foo == "abc" then
    foo = "xyz"

  else
    foo = "abc"

  end

end
```

Can I archive this shorter?
Anything similar to

```
foo = not foo
```

My first attempt had been

```
foo = (foo and not "abc") or "xyz"
```

But of course this doesn't work =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way is to do this:

`foo = (foo == "abc") and "xyz" or "abc"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a table as a transition map:

```
function switch_state()
  local transit = { abc = "xyz", xyz = "abc" }
  foo = transit[foo]
  return foo
end
```

Comment: Nice way for a self-made switch-statement but for only 2 states, it's a little overkill i guess. In the end it's not simpler than my if-then.

Comment: Nice. (Don't you also want to pass foo into the function?  If it's global you don't need to return it.)

Comment: @tonypdmtr yes you can certainly do that. I didn't here just to keep it close to the OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this:

Store `foo` as a boolean value and toggle using `foo = not foo`.

When you need the string use `foo and "abc" or "xyz"`

```
function toggle_state()
  foo = not foo
end

function state()
   return foo and "abc" or "xyz"
end
```

Comment: Could lead to trouble if the values change in the future. Sure a way, but ivos is better.